# Python random module shuffle keeps returning same output

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to get a random pair of colors from a Python list. Here is my code so far:

```
from random import *

color_choices = ['#FAACA8', '#DDD6F3', '#21D4FD', '#B721FF', '#08AEEA', '#2AF598', '#FEE140', '#FA709A', '#8EC5FC', '#E0C3FC', '#FBAB7E', '#F7CE68', '#D9AFD9', '#97D9E1', '#FBDA61', '#FF5ACD', '#F76B1C']
shuffle(color_choices)
print(color_choices)
```

The problem is the it keeps returning the same "random" order on each run of the program

```
['#21D4FD', '#FBDA61', '#B721FF', '#F76B1C', '#FBAB7E', '#DDD6F3', '#E0C3FC', '#2AF598', '#F7CE68', '#FF5ACD', '#FEE140', '#FA709A', '#8EC5FC', '#08AEEA', '#FAACA8', '#97D9E1', '#D9AFD9']
```

I ran the program three times. It cannot be a coincidence that the shuffle will return all colors in the exact same order three times.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of `shuffle`?

Comment: Are you setting the random number seed someplace?  It should default to the current time of day unless you explicitly set it.

Comment: Try calling `random.seed()` before execution.

Comment: @ScottHunter I am importing the random module from Python.

Comment: Can't reproduce - you may have a `random.py` file in your current directory.

Comment: @rassar No, there is no such file. I checked just now. :)

Comment: However, `random` module was imported twice. Can that be a problem?

Comment: @hmm calling `random.seed()` worked. Do we have to call it every time we need to shuffle or is my program doing something weird?

Comment: You should call `random.seed()` at the start of the program.

Comment: @hmm: How does one call a function "before execution"?

Comment: @ScottHunter Before execution ... of shuffle.

Comment: @ScottHunter If you don't call `random.seed()`, it uses the current time of day to initialize its state.  The only time you need to call it is if you want to have a reproducible sequence.